# passing a pointer to a class method as a function argument

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class

```
class A{
    A(/*constructor arguments*/);
    double MethA(double);
};
```

And I want to pass the method `MethA` in a function that takes a pointer to a function :

```
double function(double (*f)(double), double x){
    return f(x);
}
```

So  what I'm doing is to call

```
A a(/*constructor arguments*/);
function(a.MethA,1.0);
```

but it doesn't compile.

I'm pretty sure that this question is answered somewhere else, but I couldn't find where because I'm not sure that the terminology I use is correct. Am I trying to pass a pointer on a class method as a function argument ? Or, to pass a function pointer as a member of a class... I'm confused :-(

Comment: Please spell correctly. `class` is lower-case, and you need a semicolon at the end. Details, but programming is all about details.

Comment: Why write code at best is incomprehensible? You got virtual functions. Pass in an object that has one of those and make the code readable

Comment: a pointer to a member function has a different type than a function pointer

Comment: @Tim, this is why i guess I'm lost... I don't understand exactly what type I need to pass in order to call `MethA` within `function`

Comment: Is the function you are passing it to one that you wrote? If not, then you need a wrapper function.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure i understand your question, I wrote everything that is contained in the class A and function

Comment: Do you have(and are you allowed to use) a C++11 compiler? There is an easier way to do what I think you want to do without mucking about with member function pointers. Member function pointers probably won't do exactly what you want anyway.

Comment: @Tim I will run the code on different clusters, some have C++11, some don't. In any case, I'm curious to know the simpler solution...

Comment: It's cumbersome but doable without lambdas. You pass your parameter as a function object. You can use templates to avoid spelling out the type. The extra baggage gets optimized away by the compiler. Shall I post an answer?

Comment: @Tim, If you don't mind... It will help me a lot ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to use a pointer to member function, you need to pass two separate things:

- what member function to call and
- what instance to call it on.

In C++, you can't combine them in one construct, like you want to:

```
A a;
bar(a.foo);
```

is not valid C++.

Instead, you have to do this:

```
A a;
bar(a, &A::foo)
```

And declare and implement bar() accordingly:

```
void bar(A &a, void (A::*method)()) {
    a.*method();
}
```

Comment: got this to work by wrapping (a.*method)() in the body of bar in parens.

Answer (score 1):

See [Arkadiy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20745625/880984) answer if you want to see how to properly use member function pointers.

**BUT**

**As requested in the comments**: if the compiler you are using supports lambdas (some without full C++11 do). You can do something like the following, which looks more like the syntax you are attempting to use.

Your definition for `function` changes to something like:

```
template <typename F>
double function(F f, double x){
    return f(x);
};
```

a function template that accepts a parameter that is callable with a `double`.

At your call-site you do this:

```
A a(/*constructor arguments*/);
function([&](double x){return a.MethA(x);},1.0);
```

That generates a function object in-place that is bound to your class instance `a` by reference.

The template can be made fully typesafe with some magic in `<type_traits>`, but as-is it will give you template spew if you pass something very wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a static function!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
class A {
public:
  static double MethA(double x) { return 5 * x; }
};
typedef double (*ftype)(double);
double function(ftype f) {
  assert(f != NULL);
  return f(7);
}
int main(int, char**) {
  // expect "35\n" on stdout
  std::cout << function(A::MethA) << "\n";
}
```

It has to be static because you can't access any of A's variables without knowing which A object are you refering to!  If you need A's non-static member variables, you need to pass a reference to an a into the static function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
class A {
  double fX;
public:
  A(double x) : fX(x) { }
  double methB(double x) const { return fX * x; }
  static double MethB(double x, const A& a) {
    return a.methB(x);
  }
};
typedef double (*ftype2)(double, const A&);
double function_with_context(ftype2 f, const A& a) {
  assert(f != NULL);
  return f(7, a);
}

int main(int, char**) {
  A a(6);
  // expect "42\n" on stdout
  std::cout << function_with_context(A::MethB, a) << "\n";
}
```

But it's sometimes better to use inheritance and polymorphism to achieve this sort of interface:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyInterface {
public:
  virtual double f(double x) const = 0;
};

class A : public MyInterface {
  double fX;
public:
  A(double x) : fX(x) { }
  double f(double x) const {
    return fX * x;
  }
};

double function(const MyInterface& o) {
  return o.f(7);
}

int main(int, char**) {
  A a(6);
  // expect "42\n" on stdout
  std::cout << function(a) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: okay, this solutions works for me... but i don't understand the effect of declaring the method as static. Is it good programing? Will it work if my class is a class template?

Comment: It means you can't access any of A's variables.  After all, which A object are you refering to?